# Bitte um Hilfe mit einem Songtext - CRO

Tags: lyrics

Es geht um CRO Bye-Bye song
Die Texte die man im Internet finden stimmen nicht mit was ich hoere

Hier is die Version
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=huBNgxolXFo

mit der genauen Zeitpunkt:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=huBNgxolXFo#t=18

Die Zeile
Lyrics-sites behapten das 
"Er ist auf dem Weg nach Hause mit der Bahn"
zu sein,
mir aber klingt es als  "Er sorgt um Weg nach Hause ..?? "

Native speaker help wanted :)

Danke

Comment: Das Bärchen singt wirklich *Er is(t) auf dem Weg nach Hause mit der Bahn* -   Nur sehr ungewöhnlich betont durch den Rap-Rythmus.

Comment: Hinweis auf 't' die ausfaelt erklaert schon etwas :).
Danke, tofro

Comment: Du hast den „Lyrics-Sites“ nicht geglaubt, warum glaubst du der Q&A-Site?

Comment: Es kommt haufig vor, dass Lyrcs sites einander replizierten  - habe mit anderen Texten schon Erfarng gehabt wo falshen Texten in meheren Sites verteilt waren und der Untershied mit Original wirklich wesentlich war. Auserdem mehrere Performance-Versionen gibt es auch und die koennen auch von einander abwiegen. Deswegen fragte ich einen genauen Version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da hast du dich verhört. Die Lyrics-Zeile ist korrekt. Er "verschluckt" nur  die Silben etwas, wodurch es ein wenig undeutlich ist. Er singt aber eindeutig "Er ist auf dem Weg nach Hause mit der Bahn".

Comment: Natuerlich habe ich mich verhoert, denn um Weg zu sorgen kaum ein Sinn hier macht :).  Ich wollte aber meinen Zweifel beseitigen. Danke Awita